# Generalization of the Coulomb Force to the Lorentz-Force - Is it "guessing"?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, tensor-calculus, maxwell-equations, covariance

it's me again, and I'm still stuck with the paper [Generalization of Coulomb’s law to Maxwell’s equations using special relativity](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.14521) by Kobe, like in my [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/421699/).

My problem now lies in chapter 6: The author looks at the relativistic version of newtons 2nd law for a motionles charge,
\begin{align}
\frac{dp^i}{d\tau} = \frac{q}{c} E^i \gamma = \frac{q}{c} F^{i0}u_0
\end{align}

And then concludes that since the equation is proportional in the Tensors $F$ and $u$, in general there has to hold the equation:

\begin{align}
\frac{dp^i}{d\tau} = \frac{q}{c} F^{i\nu}u_\nu
\end{align}

Is this a valid derivation? To state it in a more mathematical way: 
Given the 4-vectors $a$ and $b$ and the tensor c: If I can always find a reference system with 
\begin{align}
a^i = c^{i0}b_0
\end{align}
Does this mean that

\begin{align}
a^i = c^{i\nu}b_\nu
\end{align}
in every reference frame? I tried to solve it myself, but I'm just turning arround the same arguments in my head all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three equations
$$
a^i = c^{i0}b_0
$$
between components of four-tensors $a,b,c$ are not enough to conclude the equations

$$
a^i = c^{ik}b_k
$$
are valid.

For a counterexample, consider the equation ($u$ is 4-velocity, $x$ coordinate four-vector):
$$
u^i = \frac{1}{c^2}u^iu^0 \left( - \frac{1}{2}u_0\right) ~~~~(*)
$$
Here, $\frac{1}{c^2}u^iu^0$ stand for components of a 2-rank tensor $u\otimes u/c^2$ and $-\frac{1}{2}u_0$ stands for zeroth component of 4-vector $b = -\frac{1}{2}u$.

In this case, there is always a frame where
$$
- \frac{1}{2}u^0u_0 = c^2
$$
because this equation is actually equation for the Lorentz gamma factor
$$
\frac{1}{2}\gamma^2c^2  =  c^2
$$
and there is always a frame where the particle has gamma factor $\sqrt{2}$.

In that frame the equation (*) is valid for all $i$. However, the equation
$$
u^i = \frac{1}{c^2}u^iu^\nu \frac{1}{2}u_\nu
$$
is not generally valid - it can be rewritten as
$$
u^i = -\frac{1}{2}u^i
$$
which is obviously not true.

The original Kobe's argument is somewhat different, I think. In addition to
$$
\frac{dp^i}{d\tau} = \frac{q}{c} F^{i0}u_0
$$
he also assumes that this is valid only if the particle's velocity is zero. Then that equation can be expressed this way:
$$
\frac{dp^i}{d\tau} = \frac{q}{c} F^{i\nu}u_\nu,
$$
because $u_i = 0$. But such equation between the four-vector components is, due to its form, valid in all Lorentz frames, so it is Lorentz-covariant. He then probably argues that this covariance is something we expect and demand from a physical law, we should assume that the actual forces obey this equation, even when the particle's velocity is not zero, i.e. when $u_i \neq 0$.

Comment: I just spotted something that I'm concerned about: At this stage in Kobe's Paper, he doesn't yet know that the $F^{00}$ component is zero. So he can't generalize the statement to a proper tensor equation, because $i$ just runs from 1 to 3.