# Deducting from a special case that the electric field transforms as a 2nd rank tensor: Vanishing divergence concludes vanishing vector field?

Tags: electromagnetism, tensor-calculus, coulombs-law

I'm (as in the [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/421699/generalization-of-the-gauss-law-to-a-lorentz-covariant-law-in-paper-of-kobe-is)) still working with [Kobe's Paper](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.14521). I try to understand his reasoning (given in Appendix A) why the electric field components should be components of a 2nd rank tensor. As I understand the argument, Kobe chooses a special situation where we know how the charge distribution changes, and finds out that the old and the new components are linked in the same way a 2nd rank tensor would transform in this special case. 
In short: The Author chooses a charge distribution $j^0$ with X-symmetry in a static situation (no moving charges). Further choosing suitable boundary conditions, the electric field has no X-component, $\vec{E}= (0,E_2,E_3)^T$. The author then performs a lorentz-boost in x-direction.

Coulombs law in the new system is (i runs from 1 to 3):
\begin{align}
\partial'_i E'^i= \frac{4 \pi}{c} j'^0
\end{align}

Using the fact that $\partial'_i = \partial_{\mu} \Lambda^{\mu}_i$ and that $\partial_0 E'^i=0$ (2nd one follows from the x-symmetry of the initial setup) the author concludes that:

\begin{align}
\partial_k (\Lambda^k_i E'^i - \Lambda^0_0 E^k) = 0
\end{align}

**Now comes the step I don't understand:** The author claims that since the two quantities in the bracket do linearly depend on each other, it follows in general that 
\begin{align}
(\Lambda^k_i E'^i - \Lambda^0_0 E^k) = 0
\end{align}

Can somebody elaborate on what the author means here? 
I tried to come up with an explanation, but I failed: We can interpret the quantity in the brackets by components of a 3 dimensional vector field, counted by k (k indicates the spatial component), whose divergence vanishes. My thoughts now were that the lorenz transformation transforms the quantities in a way where the rotation vanishes as well, because it was assumed to vanish in the original frame. But I a) don't know if this is a true property of rotations (to vanish in any reference frame if it vanishes in one), and b) there can be nonzero vector fields whose divergence and rotation both do vanish.

Comment: the superscripts on the last equation don't match ($j$ vs $k$).

Comment: Yes, true. I will edit the question.